# Platform exception: PlatformException(already_active, File picker is already active, null, null) in Work profile

Tags: flutter, filepicker

I have two profiles in my phone, personal and work profile. The file picker I am using works well in the personal profile, but when I try to use the same file picker in the work profile, I get the error mentioned below.

```
[MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception: PlatformException(already_active, File picker is already active, null, null)
E/flutter (16388): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(already_active, File picker is already active, null, null)
E/flutter (16388): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
E/flutter (16388): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
E/flutter (16388): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16388): #2      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:496:35)
E/flutter (16388): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16388): #3      FilePickerIO._getPath (package:file_picker/src/file_picker_io.dart:92:33)
E/flutter (16388): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16388): #4      _UploadFileWidgetState.selectFile (package:feeta/views/other_widgets/upload_file_widget.dart:40:32)
E/flutter (16388): <asynchronous suspension>
```

This is the code of `FilePicker` I am using:

```
Future<void> selectFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
      allowMultiple: false,
    );

    if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
      File selected = File(result.files.single.path!);
      String fileExtension = selected.path.split('.').last.toLowerCase();

      if (fileExtension == 'pdf' || fileExtension == 'jpg' ||
          fileExtension == 'jpeg' || fileExtension == 'png') {
        int fileSize = selected.lengthSync();
        if (fileSize <= 1024 * 1024) {
          if (widget.dialogType == "postLeave") {
            _allLeaveViewModel.selectedFile.value = selected;
            print("SelectedFile1: ${_allLeaveViewModel.selectedFile.value}");
          } else {
            _myLeavesViewModel.selectedFile.value = selected;
            print("SelectedFile2: ${_myLeavesViewModel.selectedFile.value}");
          }
          setState(() {
            selectedFile = selected;
          });
        } else {
          showFileSizeExceededDialog();
        }
      } else {
        showInvalidFileTypeDialog();
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the dependency I am using:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^1.0.0
  #webview_flutter: ^4.2.2
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2
  #flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
  dio: ^5.3.2
  jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
  file_picker: ^5.3.3
```

Devices in which this issue is occurring:

- Redmi Note 8 - OS 12.5.2 - Android 11
- Redmi Note 8 pro - OS 12.5.10 - Android 11
- Redmi Note 9     - OS 12.5.6  - Android 11
- OnePlus 8t       - OS 13.1    - Android 13

Do I need to handle this `filePicker` differently for the work profile?
Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this problem only in the work profile, where the same code is working fine in the personal profile?
Any help or suggestion would be very helpful to me!

Answer (score 0):

Updated: `file_picker: ^5.3.3` is working flawlessly in the below-written code.

Here's the solution. I tried to implement the same functionality as yours. But the only difference is I'm using the latest version of the File Picker package. I used 5.5.0, which is the new version available for the Picker.

Use `file_picker: ^5.5.0` from link: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Source code:

```
  Future<void> selectFile() async {
    final FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          type: FileType.custom,
          allowedExtensions: <String>["pdf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png"],
        ) ??
        const FilePickerResult(<PlatformFile>[]);
        
    if (result.files.isNotEmpty) {
      final File selected = File(result.files.single.path ?? "");
      final String ext = selected.path.split(".").last.toLowerCase();
      if (ext == "pdf" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "png") {
        final int size = await selected.length();
        if (size <= 1024 * 1024) {
          // Your Code Goes Here
        } else {
          log("Size Exceeded");
        }
      } else {
        log("Invalid File Type");
      }
    } else {
      log("Nothing Picked From File Picker");
    }
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
```

Comment: file_picker: ^5.3.3 is working flawlessly in the above-written code.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion of upgrading the dependency version from `file_picker: ^5.3.3` to `file_picker: ^5.5.0`, but the same problem persists. It works fine in the personal profile but throws the same error in the work profile.

Comment: Comment your code & use the above-written function in both places in your personal & work profile. & feel free to provide an update for the same.

Comment: No difference, I replace my code with your code, still the same problem persists.

Comment: Try to close Android Studio / VS Code no matter what you've been using & uninstall the installed app from the emulator / physical device. And try the whole thing again.

Comment: @DharamBudh i'm using the version you told but it's still the same error on Android 11 all other android versions working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer try to stop the app and follow these steps:

1. Run the command `Flutter clean`
2. Run the command `Flutter pub get`
3. Then run the app

This works fine with me.